# Get an image size in bytes

Tags: objective-c

I am doing it in 2 ways, and both gives wrong answer.

```
NSMutableArray *img=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
img=[memoInstance getTempImagesToSend]; //get nsmutableArray of images
NSData* myEncodedImageData=[img objectAtIndex:0];    
NSLog(@"IMAGE1:%@",[UIImage imageWithData:myEncodedImageData]); //i see image

NSLog(@"len:%lu",(unsigned long)[myEncodedImageData length]); //first way to show size

NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:myEncodedImageData], 1);
NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]); //second way to show
```

first way: `len:34898`

second way: `Size of Image(bytes):47701`

the image is from photo album,took with iphone. it cant be 47k... should be like ±500k

Comment: the `JPEG` is a compressed format... so, it can be that size.

Comment: What is de resolution and depth in bits of your image? Sizes used on disk may differ from actual size as a disk has a file system which may write in clusters. E.g. A file of 122 bytes would consume two clusters, if a cluster has a size of 64 bytes. So the file on disk would be 128 bytes large, but only contains 122 bytes of information.

Comment: @holex png gives me same result . and its strange because when you send the same image to email its about 500k ... so 40 is wrong.

Comment: I agree with @MikedeKlerk's question, what is _width_, _height_ and _depth_ of the original image? It could be an answer why you think the 500+ kB would be the better size of the file...

Comment: its an image from the phone library . the assetLibrary. its never ever 40k. iphone camera provides more that that . i dont want compressed image-even if it is compressed, i want original size, and the question is , how would i get the original size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:myEncodedImageData], 1);
```

for

```
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((your_ui_image), 0.5)];
```

Comment: i did that, if i log the size of the nsdata, i get many bytes on screen and the size i get is still 29115... is it 29k or am i wrong ?

Comment: @Rant As **Mike de Klerk** said, it's possible that your file's size depends on the file system it's on. Try to check the actual size by transferring the picture on your Mac, just to be sure

Comment: its strange. if i send that image over email, i get to choose between sizes. the first size i have there is the size i see on my log, and its the SMALLEST size. the actual size -it says that its 1.8m .... so somehow the size that the representation gives me is the smallest. i want the actuall size or at least half of it ... so i dont get Mike's answer ..

Comment: @Rant Mail might re-compress your picture, or do whatever they want to optimize the mail's sending time : transfer it on your computer to see the original size

Comment: its still not relevant. image taken with iphone is never 50k. so , question is :::: how would i get it at original size, to send to server. thats it. there is a gap here, so i dont understand your answer. but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Rant It was a comment, not an answer. But the clue is, the file size in actual bytes (almost always) differs from the bytes it `consumes` on your disk. Theoretically your image would use 47701 bytes of storage, but in `practice` on the disk it requires (47701 / sizeofcluster(4096?)) = 11.64 rounded to 12 clusters * 4096 = 49152 bytes on disk...

E.g:You cannot transport the contents of 2.5 cups of coffee in 2 and a half cups. You would require 3 cups in practise to transport the contents of only 2.5 cups. The coffee is your actual file size in bytes, whereas the cup is the cluster on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
int height = image.size.height; int width = image.size.width; 
int bytesPerRow = 4*width; 

if (bytesPerRow % 16) 
bytesPerRow = ((bytesPerRow / 16) + 1) * 16; 

int dataSize = height*bytesPerRow;
```